# Counting levels of embedding in string with Python

Tags: python, regex, match

I have strings like the following, and I'd like to calculate the maximum depth that that the string can enter.

```
//node[@cat="ssub"]//node[@cat and node[@rel="cmp" and @root="te" and @pos="comp"] and node[@rel="body" and @cat="inf" and node[@rel="hd" and @wvorm="inf" and @pos="verb"] and node[@rel="vc" and @cat="ppart" and node[@rel="hd" and @pos="verb"]]]]
```

If you enter the above code into this [beautifier](http://bramvanroy.be/projects/xpath-beautifier/) (disclaimer: my tool), you'll see what I mean by levels: the level of indentation. The string above should thus return 3. I got that, with this Python script:

```
def count_depth(xpath):
    depth = 0
    max_depth = 0
    for c in xpath:
        if c == "[":
            depth += 1
        elif c == "]":
            depth -= 1

        if depth > max_depth:
            max_depth = depth

    return max_depth
```

Easy enough. However, some string also contain `[` and `]` that I do not wish to count, such as:

```
//node[@cat="smain" and node[@rel="mod" and @cat="mwu" and node[@rel="mwp" and @pt="lid" and number(@begin) < ../number(../node[@rel="predc" and @pt="adj"]/@begin)]] and node[@rel="predc" and @pt="adj"]]
```

As you can see there is an argument `number` that causes an additional indentation i the beautifier, because there is a `node[`string present. Because of this, my above function also counts these `[`'s, which I don't want. In the example I just posted, I would want the output 2, even though I now get 3.

I am guessing I'll need to write a completely different function with regexes and lookbehind, and/or lookahead instead of looping through each character?

Comment: I'd suggest a real parser for that, so you wouldn't have to dive into edge cases needlessly. Sadly, I haven't found standalone XPath parser, so you'd have to look at some project like `lxml`, or maybe write something on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first removing the culprit (i.e. `number(...`) from the string and only then start counting. `lv_xpath` is the original XPath string.

```
r_numberless = re.compile(r"(?:and )?number\(@begin\).*?\/@begin\)")
numberless_xpath = r_numberless.sub("", lv_xpath)
lv_x_levels = count_depth(numberless_xpath)

def count_depth(xpath):
    depth = 0
    max_depth = 0
    for c in xpath:
        if c == "[":
            depth += 1
        elif c == "]":
            depth -= 1

        if depth > max_depth:
            max_depth = depth

    return max_depth
```